# Probability of occurrences of two dependent instances

Tags: probability

This should be a simple question but I can't get my hand around it:

Suppose I have a "wheel of fortune" situation in which the wheel contains 100 "slots". 5 of them will result in prize "X", while 4 of them will result in prize "Y". What is the probability of getting 20 occurrences of X and 15 occurrences of Y in a given number of "spins" (lets say 1000)?

Comment: It's pretty damn unlikely. Hell it's pretty unlikely you get just 1 occurrence of X. Since we are taking objects with replacement, this will be a direct result of multinomial theory: http://www.randomservices.org/random/bernoulli/Multinomial.html